# What is "Carpet LAN"?

Tags: local-area-network

I've been given this homework for my "Internet Engineering" class and I couldn't find anything on the internet?
What is "Carpet LAN" ? And he gave no more information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where in our FAQ, which I'm sure you've read, does it say that this site is for answering homework questions?

Comment: There is not a mention in the SF FAQ proper but Meta has a long/interesting CW on homework etiquette.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: But the first line says "Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity".

Comment: Have you tried attending class?

Comment: I would add: "... and those training for such a career."

Comment: Sneaker Net...? ;)

Answer (score 2):

seems to be some kind of radio field based radar and data transmission scheme.

http://www.springerlink.com/content/avj1pyb25x3xr3n6/

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, and I can't find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine, either.